# Setting up PHPMyAdmin on a server running Apache2 and PHP-FastCGI

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, apache2, fastcgi

I was able to install PHPMyAdmin through the command line on my new Ubuntu server. But now when I try to access it I get "You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/index.php on this server.".

I believe it has to do with these lines in the .conf file for it since they refer to mod_php and I am using php-fastcgi instead of mod-php (for memory usage purposes).

```
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
            AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

            php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
            php_flag track_vars On
            php_flag register_globals Off
            php_admin_flag allow_url_fopen Off
            php_value include_path .
            php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/lib/phpmyadmin/tmp
            php_admin_value open_basedir /usr/share/phpmyadmin/:/etc/phpmyadmin/:/var/lib/phpmyadmin/
    </IfModule>
```

I have tried commenting out the  tags, but the php settings don't work outside of it so there must be a way to do this with PHP FastCGI. Does anyone know how to do this?

I am new to using PHP FastCGI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I just had to add to the option "ExecCGI" to the apache.conf file for PHPMyAdmin. I had to put this under (within) the directory tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the file ownership if it is for web user, on phpmyadmin directory